# SQL Server repeating data

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, syntax

I am working on a string that counts quantity made with the item name. The error I am getting is that the first column `[Doc No]` is being shared on other rows on this view.

This leads me to getting an inaccurate sum.

Example:

This SQL statement should give me the answer 2.

```
SELECT  
    Item, Sum(WOQtyOrdered) As Quantity
FROM 
    [DLI-US].[dbo].[qryrptWorkOrder]
WHERE 
    [Doc No] = 10017 
GROUP BY
    Item
```

but is instead giving me 8.

When I try to use this SQL statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM [DLI-US].[dbo].[qryrptWorkOrder]
WHERE [Doc No] = 10017
```

There are 4 rows with this supposed distinct number.

The row is being repeated again, granted the data is slightly different in minor ways but not on the data that matters to me it is still the same. I am doing this on a view not sure if that means anything. But i wonder is there anything i can do to just count the `[Doc No]` once for it and to grab the `WOQtyOrdered` from that row once and then move on to the next `[Doc No]`.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you looking for a count, or a sum?

Comment: try changing SUM to MIN.

Comment: the problem is that, if there are several rows with the same DocNo, each row could have a different WOQtyOrdered; chances are, you need to understand the situation better; however, if you just want one, you can use GROUP BY and min/max/avg to choose which value of WOQtyOrdered you want.

Comment: really sounds to me like the view needs fixing.  The problem with trying to restrict your result set to one of every type of id (windowed functions come to mind also) is that it becomes hard to guarantee that you get the same row back query after query as the underlying data changes.  Maybe that's not a problem in your use case, but it gives me the heebie jeebies.

Comment: @okaram no, the WOQtyOrdered is the same on that particular doc no. I have worse ones where the doc number is repeated 9 times and its always the same qty. Its not qty that has changed but irrelevant column data i dont need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to get is `count()` and `MIN()` of `WOQtyOrdered` column like

```
SELECT  Item, 
MIN(WOQtyOrdered) As Min_Quantity,
COUNT(WOQtyOrdered) AS Quantity
FROM [DLI-US].[dbo].[qryrptWorkOrder]
Where [Doc No] = 10017 
Group by Item
```